# Selecting the SHAPE column in Toad

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, geometry, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, client

I've noticed that SQL clients select the `SHAPE` column from `SDE.ST_GEOMETRY` in different ways:

```
select shape from roads
```

- Toad: `SDE.ST_GEOMETRY(1,1,666666.0,4444444.5,666666.0,4444444.5,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0,300051,(BLOB))`
- SQL Developer: `[SDE.ST_GEOMETRY]`
- MS Access: `Error: Invalid field definition 'SHAPE' in definition of index or relationship`*. (I know MS Access isn't a real SQL client; but it helps demonstrate the point.)*

---

**Question:**

What does the text that is returned from Toad represent? Is it the properties of the blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TOAD* writes out the meta data of Oracles `ST_GEOMETRY` UDT implementation for ESRIs *SDE*; it's essentially a list of geometric predicates describing the geometry, and the vertex array that builds the geometry type, held as `BLOB`:

```
ST_GEOMETRY(
  <ENTITY>,    -- geometry type (POINT, LINESTRING, ...)
  <NUMPTS>,    -- number of points
  <MINX>,      -- coordinates of the envelope (bbox)
  <MINY>,      -- ^
  <MAXX>,      -- ^
  <MAXY>,      -- ^
  <MINZ>,      -- range of Z values
  <MAXZ>,      -- ^
  <MINM>,      -- range of M values
  <MAXM>,      -- ^
  <AREA>,      -- area in CRS units (if any)
  <LEN>,       -- length in CRS units (if any)
  <SRID>,      -- CRS identifier
  <POINT_BLOB> -- vertex storage
)
```

as described in detail in [ST_Geometry storage in Oracle](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002n0000006m000000).

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that TOAD dev team would have gone out of their way to do this (account for ESRI's implementation of ST_GEOMETRY).